# Pass Value to BeforeSendRequest in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, iclientmessageinspector

I want to pass additional value( GUID, different for each request) to the `BeforeSendRequest` in WCF `IClientMessageInspector` interface. This value not include in the request object. How can I pass this value to the `BeforeSendRequest` method?

Comment: A quick win would be writing a singleton class, and read this value in the BeforeSendRequest method.

Comment: Whats the connection between the GUID value and the message?

Comment: Thanks Herr... I have API which is developed using WCF. Client applications are connect to this API (Service 1) and API calls another WCF service (service 2) to get data. So clients generate GUID and send that with the request. I want attach this GUID to the header of the 2nd wcf request (service 1 to service 2).
I implement IClientMessageInspector interface in service 1. So now I want to pass that GUID to BeforeSendRequest for attach to the WCF header. How can I do this.

Comment: If you can modify the code of the API, you can get the incoming guid from the OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders and add this guid to the OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.
[link](http://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/)

Comment: If you can't you can implement both IDispatchMessageInspector and  IClientMessageInspector interfaces. Read the incoming guid in the AfterReceiveRequest, store it in a threadstatic variable, and add to the outgoing headers in the BeforeSendRequest.

Comment: Thank you Herr.... You save my life ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class WcfMessageInterceptor : IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static string service1GUID;

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        service1GUID = request.Headers.GetHeader("service1-guid-header", "s");
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var serviceName="";
        if (channel != null && channel.RemoteAddress != null)
        {
            var tmp = request.Headers.Action.Substring(0, request.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf('/'));
            serviceName = tmp.Substring(tmp.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        }
        var methodName = request.Headers != null
                                ? request.Headers.Action.Substring(request.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)
                                : "Action";
        //check if the called service is the right one
        if(serviceName=="Service2"){
            var typedHeader = new MessageHeader(service1GUID);
            var untypedHeader = typedHeader.GetUntypedHeader("service1-guid-in-service2-header", "s");
            request.Headers.Add(untypedHeader);
        }
    }
}
```